# Basis for the polynomial linear transformation problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

So the question asks: Consider the transformation T:ℙ2→ℙ2, where ℙ2 is the space of second-degree polynomials matrices, given by $T(f)=f(3)+f′(3)(t−3)$. Find the matrix for this transformation relative to the standard basis =$1,t,t^2$. What is the basis for $im(T)$ suggested by the matrix B? What is a basis for $ker(T)$?

So so far I got B=$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&-9\\ 0&1&6\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$

And to find the kernel, let $f(t)=0$, and I got

$Ker(T) = t^2+9-6t$

And I thought the image of the matrix would be {1,0,0},{0,1,0}

But it was marked wrong, (Kernal and the B matrix are correct). Why is the basis of the image not  {1,0,0},{0,1,0}? So how can I find $im(T)$ suggested by the matrix B?

Comment: You are right about the basis, it really spans the image. But you are asked to find the basis suggested by the matrix $B$.

Comment: Because $Im(T)$ is a subspace of $P_2$, the set $\lbrace (1,0,0),(0,1,0) \rbrace$ does not generate $Im(T)$, what generates it is $\lbrace 1, x \rbrace$

Comment: @M.LeventDoğan Thanks! But I think I am a little confused. How can I make {(1,0,0),(0,1,0)} the image of the Im(T)? Or how can I find Im(T)?

Comment: @Eliana Thanks! But how can I find Im(T)?

Comment: $Im(T)$ is isomorphic to the subspace generated by the column vectors of any matrix associated to $T$, you can easily check that the third column of your matrix is a linear combination of the first and second columns and the first and the second ones are not colinear, so they are a basis for a subspace isomorphic to $Im(T)$. The vectors of $P_2$ with coordinates (in the standard basis) $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0)$ form a basis for $Im(T)$, and those vectors are $1(1)+0(x)+0(x^2)$ and $0(1)+1(x)+0(x^2)$.

Comment: @Eliana Thanks your explanation helps a lot!